# I want to retrieve mysql rows apart from id's which are stored in array in php

Tags: php

Now I want to retrieve those rows from worker table which are not in `worker_id` array:

```
$worker_id=explode(",", $worker_id);
echo 'Using Explode';
print_r($worker_id);
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use explode... Use this query

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Table.id NOT IN ($worker_id)";
```

Infact the query should be like

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Table.id NOT IN (2,3,4,5)";
```

Comment: At run time the query forms as:

Comment: what is the response ?

Comment: then please mark the answer right if u think it's correct